# lmerTest::anova not showing p-values

Tags: r, lme4, lmertest

I am asking a new question because the dublicate ([anova() does not display p-value when used with lmerTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20209237/anova-does-not-display-p-value-when-used-with-lmertest)) is not really providing an answer: 
I ran into the same problem that lmerTest::anova will not output degrees of freedom and p-values for a specific model (that is much less complicated than the one in the post mentioned above):

```
DirectionFit <- lmer(Similarity ~  picture_category * ComparisonType + (1 + picture_category + ComparisonType|Subject), data = DirectionData, REML=FALSE)
```

I noticed, that the model report includes the convergence code 0 and that there have been 2 optimizer warnings. Could it be that it is because of this that lmerTest::anova is not reporting p-values? 
The output of the model itself looks normal, just with very high AIC, BIC etc (-10625). 
Does anyone know what to do about this? I have read that maybe another optimizer should be chosen, but would that also solve the convergence problem? 
Any help is appreciated!

**Edit:**
I uploaded my data on: http://www.sharecsv.com/s/1e303e9cef06d02af51ed5231385b759/TestData.csv
Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think we would need a reproducible example to try to trouble-shoot this ...

Comment: That sound reasonable, the link in the question contains the data. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic problem is that you have a *singular fit*; the estimated random-effects variance-covariance matrix is on the boundary of its feasible space (equivalently, one of the internal parameters that `lme4` uses to characterize the variance-covariance matrix, which must be non-negative, is exactly zero). This is *not* an optimization problem *per se*; it generally means your model is too complex for your data, and should be simplified (e.g. see the relevant section in the [GLMM FAQ](http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#singular-fit) for more information).  In particular, although your experimental design *in principle* allows you to fit among-subject variation in effects of `picture_category` and `ComparisonType`, hoping to estimate a 4x4 variance-covariance matrix for the random effect from 39 subjects is very optimistic. (You may be following Barr et al's "keep it maximal advice" ...)

What follows may be more technical than you really want, but I'm providing it as future reference for trouble-shooting these kinds of problems. If you want to ignore the fact that your model is singular (which I wouldn't recommend), and you are willing to fix a bug in the current version of `lmerTest` [I'm sending the maintainer an e-mail]), you can actually get p-values for this problem via Kenward-Roger approximation: `summary(m2, ddf="Kenward-Roger")` works, although it's quite slow (163 seconds on my laptop).

---

Because `lmerTest` intercepts error messages, making it hard to see what has happened, I generally try to trouble-shoot `lmerTest` problems by starting with `lme4`.

Fit model:

```
DirectionData <- read.csv("TestData.csv")
library(lme4)
DirectionFit <- lmer(Similarity ~  picture_category * ComparisonType +
           (1 + picture_category + ComparisonType|Subject),
                     data = DirectionData, REML=FALSE)
## Warning messages:
## 1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
##   unable to evaluate scaled gradient
## 2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
##   Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues
```

OK, Let's look at what happened. `summary(DirectionFit)`, and particularly `VarCorr(DirectionFit)`, doesn't show us any 0 variances or +/-1 correlations, but the fit is nonetheless singular:

```
th <- getME(DirectionFit,"theta")
which(th==0)
## Subject.picture_categoryland 
##                           8
```

(it might be better in practice to test for `which(th<1e-10)`)

So how does this affect the `lmerTest` output?

```
library(lmerTest)
m2 <- as(DirectionFit,"merModLmerTest")
trace("summary",sig="merModLmerTest",browser)  ## debug
summary(m2)
```

As we dig down, we find that the trouble is in the `calcApvar` function, which has this code:

```
dd <- devfunTheta(rho$model)  ## set up deviance function
h <- myhess(dd, c(rho$thopt, sigma = rho$sigma)) ## compute Hessian
ch <- try(chol(h), silent = TRUE)
```

If we try the last command *without* silencing/catching the error message we get

> Error in chol.default(h) : the leading minor of order 10 is not positive definite

Basically, we can't Cholesky-decompose the Hessian (second-derivative) matrix because it's not positive definite: as you can read on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition), the Cholesky decomposition applies to PD matrices.

Comment: wow, thank you for that thorough answer! I was indeed trying to keep it maximal. Although I don't understand all of the technical part, I concluded (hopefully correctly) from your answer that I should make my model simpler. Now that I have only a random intercept for participants, the model runs fine. Thank you again for your help!